# How to check Grid Layout combination of letters

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've built Grid layout with 3 columns and 3 rows (3x3), each cell contains button (9 buttons in the whole grid).
I've done for each button this kind of check

```
final TextView note = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final TextView turn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    turn.setText("O");
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setText("Empty");
    button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            if(button.getText() == "Empty") {
                if (turn.getText() == "O") {
                    button.setText("O");
                    turn.setText("X");
                } else {
                    button.setText("X");
                    turn.setText("O");
                }
            }
            else {
                note.setText("NOTE: This place is taken already.");
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm checking which turn is it (if its X turn or O turn) and setting text according to the current turn.

Anyway, that works just fine, though I want to check combinations between the cells (if X or O appears 3 times in row/column/slant, I'll use `note.setText` and write "game is over, X/O won").

Is there any shorter way to check the combination I've just machined instead of using if statement for each and every one of them?

GRID LAYOUT:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"/>
 <GridLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button5"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button6"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button7"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button8"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button9"/>
</GridLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/grid"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to set up a Model to go with your View.  This could be as simple as:

```
    private char[][] mGrid = new char[3][3];
    private char mNext;  // x or o, to show who's turn it is
```

This will also help when you go to save/restore state, which you will need to do eventually.

You can simplify a little bit by using a single `OnClickListener`, like this:

```
        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick (View v) {

                    int row, col;
                    switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.button1:
                        row = 0;
                        col = 0;
                        break;
                    case R.id.button2:
                        row = 0;
                        col = 1;
                        break;

                    // etc. etc.
                    }

                    // now you have a grid, a row & column and a next 
                    // indicator to do your logic

                    mGrid[row][col] = mNext;

                    // check your game state, make any updates, ...

                    mNext = (mNext == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X'; // switch players
                }
        }

        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setText(mGrid[0][0] == '\0' ? "Empty" : Character.toString(mGrid[0][0]));
        button1.setEnabled(mGrid[0][0] != '\0'); // if it's filled, you can't click the button
        button1.setOnClickListener(listener);

        final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setText(mGrid[0][1] == '\0' ? "Empty" : Character.toString(mGrid[0][1]));
        button2.setEnabled(mGrid[0][1] != '\0'); 
        button2.setOnClickListener(listener);

        // etc.
```

Hopefully that will give you some ideas.

Comment: May you look into that and tell me why it doesn't working? http://pastebin.com/C3V5rGzs - I've done the longer way though, I can't figure out why the function checker() isn't working.